# What is the proper way to set up parameter values in test config in HP ALM?

Tags: parameters, config, alm

Not really a programming question, but maybe someone here can help....

I'm trying to figure out the best way to use test configs for parameters in test cases. From what I can tell, the process is extremely cumbersome and confusing. I must be missing something here.

How I understand it, the only way to get dynamic parameter values into a test case is to:

1) Create an excel where parameter names are defined in top row of each column

2) on row 2, set the desired parameter value for each parameter/column

3) If there are different configs for the same test, add a new row, and set parameter values for this permutation

4) Upload the excel into ALM 'Test Resources' area

5) Go to 'Test Plan', and find test case, then click on Test Configuration tab

6) On Data tab, select dynaic radio button,  and point to the resource file created above

7) Click Data Resources Settings, which brings up the Data Resources Settings popup

8) Manually set each parameter

Step 8 is where I scratch my head. Is there not a way to simply have ALM recognize the values in the config and populate them automatically? So for example, if the config sheet shows the value for `<<<param1>>> = "apple"`, Then when you upload the config sheet, any instance of `<<<param1>>>` will show "apple" on execution.

My actual test cases have complex components,. Some tests require many components. And many parameters are shared by different components. Which makes setting the parameters in step 8 above VERY confusing.

Is there as better way ?

Hopefully this made sense.

Thanks